# Depth-first search - Recursively calculate a value for a property - Suggestion for performance + bug

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am crating a recursion (Depth-first search) which need to calculate a property `rotation_absolute`. This property is computed keeping the initial value (property `rotation`) for each child of `root` and added consequentially.
Value should be start from zero when moving to the next child of root.

I wish to ask you:

- At a moment a bug is present in the code and the output is not correct, are you able to identify it?
- The data it is very big and I would like a suggestion for better perfomance.

An example for the correct result for `rotation_absolute`:

---

```
            root = 0

            a     = 10            0+10
            a-a   = 30            0+10+20
            a-b   = 10            0 +10

            b     = 50            0+50
            b-a   = 80            0+50+30
            b-a-a = 120           0+50+30+40
            b-b   = 60            0+50+10
```

Code visible at, please look at console:
https://jsbin.com/nudaculonu/edit?html,console,output

```js
   var app = {
            findChildren: function (id) {
                var result = this.data.filter(function (item) {
                    if (item.parent === id) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                return result;
            },
            data: [
                {
                    id: 'root',
                    parent: '',
                    rotation: 0
                },
                {
                    id: 'a',
                    parent: 'root',
                    rotation: 10
                },
                    {
                        id: 'a-a',
                        parent: 'a',
                        rotation: 20
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'a-b',
                        parent: 'a',
                        rotation: 0
                    },
                {
                    id: 'b',
                    parent: 'root',
                    rotation: 50
                },
                    {
                        id: 'b-a',
                        parent: 'b',
                        rotation: 30
                    },
                        {
                            id: 'b-a-a',
                            parent: 'b-a',
                            rotation: 40
                        },
                    {
                        id: 'b-b',
                        parent: 'b',
                        rotation: 10
                    },
            ],
            calculate: function () {
                var increment = 0;
                var recursion = function (item) {

                    increment += item.rotation;
                    item.rotation_absolute = increment;
                    var level2 = app.findChildren(item.id);
                    level2.forEach(function (item2) {
                        recursion.call(this, item2);
                    });
                    increment = 0;

                };


                var level1 = app.findChildren('root');
                level1.forEach(function (item) {
                    recursion.call(this, item);
                });

                console.log(this.data);

            },
        };
        /*
            results for rotation_absolute:

            root = 0

            a     = 10            0+10
            a-a   = 30            0+10+20
            a-b   = 10            0 +10

            b     = 50            0+50
            b-a   = 80            0+50+30
            b-a-a = 120           0+50+30+40
            b-b   = 60            0+50+10
        */
        app.calculate();
```

Notes:

Current output for the code produce a wrong result of:

```
a-b = 0  should be 10
b-b = 10 should be 60
```

Comment: Your information is vague?  What about it doesnt work?

Comment: @Fallenreaper thanks for your comment, if you open console and see the result for my script you get this result: b-b = 10 should be 60
a-b = 0  should be 10, so something wrong in that code, I would need some suggestion to fix it. I have added an edit to my question.

Comment: Let me take a quick look and see if i can figure it out.

Comment: are your ID always unique?  One way to make it faster is to have a MAP instead of an array.  Your filter command is going to loop over the entire Array.

Comment: Also:  I was looking at it.  It looks like `a-b` is defined as 0.  So, that would mean that you arent setting the variables?  Seems like it might be a scope thing for you to print out the data but the data is never really over written no?  Or maybe your will need a new MAP you are storing stuff in you will create that is abstracted from View?  That way you wont change the base object at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, ID are always unique, the rotation it is relative to the parent, the rotation_absolute is an absolute value calculated dynamically based on the nesting level of rotation, properties rotation are correct and should not overwritten/calculated. Please let me know if you have a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the Depth-first search and calculating the property `rotation_absolute` properly using the following code.

I am still interested to any suggestion for performance improvement.

Please note, this solution contains a more complex set of data for testing compare to the original question.

```js
var app = {
            getById: function (id) {
                var result;
                this.data.some(function (item) {
                    if (item.id === id) {
                        result = item;
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                return result;
            },
            findChildren: function (id) {
                var result = this.data.filter(function (item) {
                    if (item.parent === id) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                return result;
            },
            data: [
                {
                    id: 'root',
                    parent: '',
                    rotation: 0,
                    rotation_absolute: 0
                },
                {
                    id: 'a',
                    parent: 'root',
                    rotation: 10
                },
                    {
                        id: 'a-a',
                        parent: 'a',
                        rotation: 10
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'a-b',
                        parent: 'a',
                        rotation: 10
                    },
                        {
                            id: 'a-b-a',
                            parent: 'a-b',
                            rotation: 10
                        },
                            {
                                id: 'a-b-a-a',
                                parent: 'a-b-a',
                                rotation: 10
                            },
                                {
                                    id: 'a-b-a-a-a',
                                    parent: 'a-b-a-a',
                                    rotation: 10
                                },
                            {
                                id: 'a-b-a-b',
                                parent: 'a-b-a',
                                rotation: 10
                            },
                {
                    id: 'b',
                    parent: 'root',
                    rotation: 0
                },
                    {
                        id: 'b-a',
                        parent: 'b',
                        rotation: 10
                    },
                        {
                            id: 'b-a-a',
                            parent: 'b-a',
                            rotation: 10
                        },
                            {
                                id: 'b-a-a-a',
                                parent: 'b-a-a',
                                rotation: 10
                            },
                    {
                        id: 'b-b',
                        parent: 'b',
                        rotation: 10
                    },
            ],
            calculate: function () {
                var recursion = function (id) {
                    var children = this.findChildren(id);
                    var parent = this.getById(id);
                    children.forEach(function (item) {
                        if ('rotation_absolute' in item === false) {
                            item.rotation_absolute = 0;
                        }
                        item.rotation_absolute += item.rotation + parent.rotation_absolute;
                        recursion.call(this, item.id)
                    }, this);
                };

                recursion.call(this, 'root')
            },
        };
        app.calculate();
        console.clear();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(app.data));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a different data structure fot this problem, because you iterate over and over again for finding a node, you can use a tree for faster access and for calculation the `rotation_absolute`.

This propopsal features a tree and keeps the original array intact, just adding the new property `rotation_absolute` with the desired value.

```js
var app = {
        data: [{ id: 'root', parent: '', rotation: 0 }, { id: 'a', parent: 'root', rotation: 10 }, { id: 'a-a', parent: 'a', rotation: 20 }, { id: 'a-b', parent: 'a', rotation: 0 }, { id: 'b', parent: 'root', rotation: 50 }, { id: 'b-a', parent: 'b', rotation: 30 }, { id: 'b-a-a', parent: 'b-a', rotation: 40 }, { id: 'b-b', parent: 'b', rotation: 10 }],
        buildTree: function () {
            var o = {};
            this.data.forEach(function (a) {
                var temp = { data: a, children: o[a.id] && o[a.id].children };
                o[a.id] = temp;
                if (a.parent === '') {
                    this.tree = temp;
                } else {
                    o[a.parent] = o[a.parent] || {};
                    o[a.parent].children = o[a.parent].children || [];
                    o[a.parent].children.push(temp);
                }
            }, this);
        },
        calculate: function () {
            function sum(o) {
                o.data.rotation_absolute = this.sum + o.data.rotation
                Array.isArray(o.children) && o.children.forEach(sum, { sum: o.data.rotation_absolute });
            }
            this.tree || this.buildTree();
            sum.bind({ sum: 0 })(this.tree);
        }
    };
    
app.calculate();
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(app.data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(app.tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem has to do with javascript variable closures:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

Since increment is outside your function, it's being treated like a global variable. This can create some strange behavior.

It might be better to actually pass the increment value you need as an argument to the recursive function, then pass a 0 when you want to reset it.